# API Testing in Selenium IDE

Tags: testing, selenium-ide

How can **Selenium IDE** be utilized for **API Testing**. i.e. Pushing the request to server and getting the response.

Comment: I'm sure you could do this, but it seems like the wrong tool for the job. Selenium is better suited for E2E testing (like mimicking a user interacting with a browser). Depending on what stack you are using for your API, a good testing framework should include ways to make calls to an endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Alphonso77, it is required to fetch some token to login to UI and that token can be fetched only by hitting API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using **Javascript** - **XMLHttpRequest Method**.

Create Request, set headers & other parameters, and hit the Server with the body.

**Command :** `Execute Script`

**Target :**

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = '<URL of PAI to test>';
var method = Method to test (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE)>';
req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
req.open(method, url, false);
req.send(<{REQUEST BODY}>);
```

**Value :** `<Any variable name to store response>`

[Screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evcgx.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a Get call request using the HTTPClient library.

```
package com.qa.tests;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.qa.client.RestClient;
import com.qa.util.TestUtil;

public class GetAPITest extends TestBase {
    TestBase testBase;
    String mainURL;
    String apiURL;
    String URL;
    RestClient restClient;
    CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        testBase = new TestBase();
        mainURL = prop.getProperty("URL");
        apiURL = prop.getProperty("serviceURL");

        URL = mainURL + apiURL;
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void getAPITestWithoutHeaders() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        restClient = new RestClient();
        closeableHttpResponse = restClient.get(URL);

        // 1. Status Code
        int statusCode = closeableHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Status Code: " + statusCode);

        Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, RESPONSE_CODE_200, "Status code is not 200");

        // 2. Json String
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(closeableHttpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString);
        System.out.println("Response Jason: " + responseJson);

        // single value assertion:
        // per_page:
        String perpageValue = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(responseJson, "/per_page");
        System.out.println("Per Page value is: " + perpageValue);

        Assert.assertEquals(Integer.parseInt(perpageValue), 6);

        // total:
        String totalValue = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(responseJson, "/total");
        System.out.println("Total value is: " + totalValue);

        Assert.assertEquals(Integer.parseInt(totalValue), 12);

        // Get value from JSON Array:
        String firstName = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(responseJson, "/data[0]/first_name");
        String lastName = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(responseJson, "/data[0]/last_name");
        String id = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(responseJson, "/data[0]/id");
        String email = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(responseJson, "/data[0]/email");

        System.out.println(firstName);
        System.out.println(lastName);
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(email);

        // 3. All headers
        Header[] headersArray = closeableHttpResponse.getAllHeaders();

        HashMap<String, String> allHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (Header header : headersArray) {
            allHeaders.put(header.getName(), header.getValue());

        }

        System.out.println("Headers Array: " + allHeaders);
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void getAPITestWithHeaders() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        restClient = new RestClient();
        HashMap<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headerMap.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

        closeableHttpResponse = restClient.get(URL, headerMap);

        // 1. Status Code
        int statusCode = closeableHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Status Code: " + statusCode);

        Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, RESPONSE_CODE_200, "Status code is not 200");

        // 2. Json String
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(closeableHttpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString);
        System.out.println("Response Jason: " + responseJson);

        // single value assertion:
        // per_page:
        String perpageValue = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(responseJson, "/per_page");
        System.out.println("Per Page value is: " + perpageValue);

        Assert.assertEquals(Integer.parseInt(perpageValue), 6);

        // total:
        String totalValue = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(responseJson, "/total");
        System.out.println("Total value is: " + totalValue);

        Assert.assertEquals(Integer.parseInt(totalValue), 12);

        // Get value from JSON Array:
        String firstName = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(responseJson, "/data[0]/first_name");
        String lastName = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(responseJson, "/data[0]/last_name");
        String id = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(responseJson, "/data[0]/id");
        String email = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(responseJson, "/data[0]/email");

        System.out.println(firstName);
        System.out.println(lastName);
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(email);

        // 3. All headers
        Header[] headersArray = closeableHttpResponse.getAllHeaders();

        HashMap<String, String> allHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (Header header : headersArray) {
            allHeaders.put(header.getName(), header.getValue());

        }

        System.out.println("Headers Array: " + allHeaders);
    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).